# What is the value of `<public context>` in nginx configuration from documentation of artifactory

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy, java

I want to deploy artifactory behind a ssl public nginx proxy.

I have read the documentation and tried many configuration.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+NGINX

I can't be sure for the value of `<public context>`.

My artifactory is accessible under `http://localhost:31937/webapp/#/home`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Leave it blank unless you're getting fancy**

I'm working with the assumptions that:

1. This is the only application stack installed to your server
2. That you're referring to this line in the nginx.conf

   proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/;

The artifactory online manual for nginx doesn't instruct you what to do with this 'public context' variable. I agree it's a little lacking. However, Artifactory's apache documentation does cover this variable. From this link: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy

**Public Context Path:**

> The path which will be publicly used to access Artifactory. If Artifactory is accessible on the root of the server leave this field empty.